# How can I change the value in a select element without name with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have three select-forms in a "div class" and "li" - see structure. I want to change the values with jQuery, but i don't know how. The names of the "select"-fields are not given. How can I realize this project? Thank you for your help.

```
<li data-v-56df6dda="">
<select autocomplete="off" data-v-56df6dda="">
<option value="122" data-v-56df6dda="">
                Bitstamp
                            </option><option value="120" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                CryptoCompare
                            </option><option value="132" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                Kraken
                            </option><option value="131" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                Admiral Markets
                            </option><option value="117" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                Coinbase Pro
                            </option></select>
</li> <!----> 

<li data-v-56df6dda="">
<select autocomplete="off" data-v-56df6dda="">
<option value="mountain" selected="selected" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                Mountain
                            </option> <option value="line" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                Linie
                            </option> <option value="candle" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                Kerzen
                            </option> <option value="ohlc" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                OHLC
                            </option> <option value="pf" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                Point &amp; Figure
                            </option> <option value="heikinashi" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                Heikin Ashi
                            </option></select>

</li> 
<li data-v-56df6dda="">
<select autocomplete="off" data-v-56df6dda="">
<option value="i" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                Intraday
                            </option> <option value="week" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                1 Woche
                            </option> <option value="month" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                1 Monat
                            </option> <option value="3month" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                3 Monate
                            </option> <option value="6month" selected="selected" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                6 Monate
                            </option> <option value="year" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                1 Jahr
                            </option> <option value="3year" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                3 Jahre
                            </option> <option value="5year" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                5 Jahre
                            </option> <option value="10year" data-v-56df6dda="">
                                10 Jahre
                            </option>
</select>
</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Add them id/name/whatever, or use nth-child selector (in jquery you can use :eq too)

Answer (score 0):

retrieve all the `<select>` with $('select').each(), then access it inside that function with $this.val()

Answer (score 0):

you can use `eq option[value=120]` for select the element requered and apply `html()`

Example:

```
 $("li:eq(0) select option[value=120]").html("Nuevo texto");

$("li:eq(0) select option[value=120]").val(130);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. So, I get the values, but how can I CHANGE the VALUES?

Comment: @HaraldLendorfer make changes to the answer

Comment: I tried your examples, but there is no effect. Its an important tip for me to use "li:eq".